# Error when deploying parse-dashboard to heroku

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-dashboard

When deploying a parse-dashboard app to heroku, I get this error:

```
Unexpected token '<'
```

What I do:

- Clone parse-dashboard repo to desktop
- Add remote to heroku
- git push heroku master

When reading similar threads, like [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/189), the recommendation is to "install from npm".

How do I go about doing this on heroku?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm an idiot. Here's the solution if someone has the same problem.

I tried to deploy the parse-dashboard to heroku, the main repo.

Instead I should have created a new app, run "npm install parse-dashboard" and then deploy that app.